# Force build to fail by some condition

Tags: c#, build, constraints

I have a class HierarchicalDictionary and some derived classes, for example Territory, Department, etc. 
And I want to control that all classes that derive from HierarchicalDictionary contain property "Hierarchy" of type of that class (Territory, Department, etc.) during build. If it is not so I want build to fail.

That is if Territory doesn't contain property Hierarchy of type Territory or Department doesn't contain property Hierarchy of type Department, build should fail.

So I want that during compilation condition checked like that (pseudocode):

```
foreach (Class1 that derive from HierarchicalDictionary)
  if(!(Class1 contains property Hierarchy of type Class1))
    build fail
```

I thought about [CodeContracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/), but I don't know if there is availability to fail by condition during build.
May be there is some proper way?

**UPD:** I'll try to describe additional limitations for my situation:

HierarchicalDictionary is not stored (in database) class. And derived classes are stored, so corresponding tables contain self reference fields in database. When I derive class "C1" from HierarchicalDictionary I mean, that this class must contain property (or field) "Hierarchy" of type "C1" exactly. Like [ClassMustContainHierarchyFieldOfMyselfType] attribute.  And I want to control that fact during compilation. If I have class "C2", that derives from HierarchicalDictionary and don't contain field (or property) "public C2 Hierarcy", build should fail.

May be there is no any "built-in" solutions. May be I can use pre- or post-build events or anything else (like CodeContracts for example)?

Comment: Is HierarchicalDictionary abstract or can it be?

Comment: HierarchicalDictionary doesn't contain any logic itself. It may contain some fields or properties. But I need some mean to say, that every derived class "C1" contains property "public C1 Hierarchy". Like attribute [ShouldContainHierarchyReferenceToMyself], that would be controlled during compilation

Answer (score 4):

If `HierarchicalDictionary` can be `abstract`, you can define the property as [`abstract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd3z1377.aspx) in the base class. This enforces a concrete implementation in every subclass.

If you need to be able to create instances of the base class `HierarchicalDictionary` you can enforce the property by adding an interface.

Comment: I don't know what the current situation is but if you needed to make concrete instances of `HierarchicalDictionary` then is there any way to do it? I'm just curious because it may be that this is necessary here...

Comment: I don't need "Hierarchy" property at HierarchicalDictionary class. And if I declare it, it would be of type HierarchicalDictionary in each derived class, wouldn't it? And I want it to be of type of certain class, where it's declared.

Answer (score 1):

Well, may be you can do something like this:

```
// GENERIC base class 
public abstract class A<T> 
{
    public abstract T GetMyType {get;}  
}

//derived ones 
public class B : A<B>
{
   public override B GetMyType
   {     
      get {
        return new B();     
      }
   }
}


public class C : A<C>
{
   public override C GetMyType 
   {     
      get  {
         return new C();        
      }
   }
}
```

and after in code:

```
new B().GetMyType.ToString(); //B 
new C().GetMyType.ToString(); //C
```

So you create constrain with *abstract method*, plus every overriden method returns its own type, as they are derived from generic base class.

Comment: I tried to clarify my question. I can't use methods because this Hierarchy property has corresponding field in datatable in database.

Comment: @mao: I edited my post to properties, check it out if that fits your needs.